# HelloWPS Tutorial GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wps

I have a problem with creating WPS-Processes for GeoServer.

I followed the "[Hello World Tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html)":

When I want to start GeoServer, the application doesn't work anymore (*"The requested resource is not available."*).

I'm using Geoserver Version 2.2.2 (with Tomcat Webserver) and Maven 2.2.1.

First I created the Folder hello_wps, added the pom.xml (edited the version number from

```
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
<version>8-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

to

```
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
<version>8.4</version>
```

Then I used the maven command "mvn eclipse:eclipse" to create the Java Project for Eclipse. I imported the project in an Eclipse workspace, created the class HelloWPS.java and added the applicationContext.xml to the folder resources.
Finally, I created the *.jar with the command "mvn clean install" (I wanted to use the option "-Pwps", but that didn't work).

I copied the *.jar-file to the .*.\apache-tomcat-7.0.33-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib* folder

What can I do??

That's the log when starting Tomcat

```
SEVERE: bean lookup error
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.geoserver.wps.gs.HelloWPS] for bean with name 'helloWPS' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-tomcat-7.0.33-windows-x86/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/hello_wps-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/process/gs/GSProcess
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1150)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.extensions(GeoServerExtensions.java:110)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.bean(GeoServerExtensions.java:291)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoaderProxy.lookupGeoServerLoader(GeoServerLoaderProxy.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoaderProxy.setApplicationContext(GeoServerLoaderProxy.java:39)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:740)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:18)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/process/gs/GSProcess
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.process.gs.GSProcess
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: Anything more descriptive in the logs? Does the rest of GeoServer still work?

Comment: Can you confirm that you built the GeoServer yourself? Is it possible you didn't enable WPS support?

Comment: I assume you checked your program worked with out being in GeoServer?

Comment: I posted the log from Tomcat.
Does "enable WPS support" mean, to install the WPS-Extension? Yes, I did.

Comment: Sorry for the question... "Anybody" deinstalled the WPS-Extension... Now it is working :-) Thank you for helping.